# Bcryptjs Compare method always returns false?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, bcrypt

Bit stumped.. my code is identical to a tutorial I'm following for this section. However, bcryptjs.compare is always returning false.

Database is mongodb and string length limit is set to 16mb from what I read so I dont think it has to do with that.

```
userModel.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
})

userSchema.methods.comparePW = async function(password) {
    console.log(await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password))
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

```
userController.js

const userModel = require('../models/userModel')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')

const userAuth = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body 

    // check if reqbody pw and email matches userModel pw/email
    const user = await userModel.findOne({ email })
    
    if (user && (await user.comparePW(password))) {
        res.send('match')
    } else {
        res.send('no match')
    }

})

module.exports = { userAuth }
```

```
dummy user filler data in the database

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const users = [
    {
        name: 'Admin',
        email: 'admin@test.com',
        password: bcrypt.hashSync('admin123, 10'),
        isAdmin: 'true',
    },
    {
        name: 'Max Smith',
        email: 'Max@test.com',
        password: bcrypt.hashSync('admin123, 10'),
    },
    {
        name: 'Jennifer Garnett',
        email: 'Jen@test.com',
        password: bcrypt.hashSync('admin123, 10'),
    },
]
  
module.exports = users
```

using console.log, the bcrypt.compare method always returns false.

Strange as this is how the tutorial has it and it seems to be working for the instructor.

Using Postman when I run a post request with email "admin@test.com" and password: "admin123" it is return false every time.

I tried reimporting the dummy data and also reloading data on mongodb compass.

Not sure what to do at this point to fix this issue? Thoughts?

Comment: After some troubleshooting, bcrypt.compare is still the problem. I managed to check if I was getting the right data back. console log of password is correct, console log of this.password is the hashed password. but bcrypt.compare is always returning false.

Answer (score 0):

While hashing the password you are combining the password and salt strength into a string like this `bcrypt.hashSync('admin123, 10')` which should be like this `bcrypt.hashSync('admin123', 10)`. If you want to work with the current situation then u need to enter password **"admin123, 10"** instead of **"admin123"**.